# To Call one python program in loop from another python program and add failed id numbers to list

Tags: python

I have a Python program and accepts the First argument ID number.

test1.py:

```
import sys

try:
    id=sys.argv[1]
    id=int(id)
    print(id)
except:
    print("Pass ID number to Program")
    
if (id!=3):
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failed 3 as exp")
    exit()
```

I have no.of ID numbers and hence want to run this program in a loop. I want to run test1.py program for failed ID numbers in the next run if len(list2)>1.

Please Note: test1.py will fail for 3 to 4 cases and I have put here one scenario.

test2.py:

```
import subprocess

list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list2 = []

for i in list1:
    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen("python test1.py i",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        print(proc.communicate[0])
    except:
        list2.append(i)
        print(list2)
```

1. i value in subprocess is not replacing
2. test1.py is an exit for a failed ID number, I am not sure how to append this to list2. If I append in test1.py then it would overwrite for the next failed ID value. Because I want to run program (test1.py) for failed ID numbers again post the loop completed for list1.

Comment: it is `Popen()`.

Comment: Why cant you `import test1`, then call a function from it?

Comment: sorry,typo Popen in question and edited question.
There is 200+ line of code in test1.py and here put sample one.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing your ID number for the program:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("python test1.py i", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

That always runs: python test1.py i

You need for example:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(f"python test1.py {i}", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

That's how that way of putting variables to strings works:

```
>>> i = 3
>>> f"python test1.py {i}"
'python test1.py 3'
```

Comment: It seems my subprocess.Popen call is wrong and generating output like this:
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]